# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" By Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have a json from the action of asp.net mvc controller,the date format like '/Date(1358753460000+0800)/',I want to parse it to the format like '2013-12-31',here is the javascript function.

The error occurs in the line which use eval function.

```
function renderTime(data){console.log('new ' + data.replace('/', '', 'g'));var da = eval('new ' + data.replace('/', '', 'g').replace('/', '', 'g'));console.log(da);return da.getFullYear() + "-" + da.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + da.getDay() + " " + da.getHours() + ":" + da.getMinutes();}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just `ToString()` the date on the server? You can have it return the date format you're looking for...

Comment: I find the answer. The problem is I don't verify the data whether is empty or not. add this "if (data.length > 0)", now it's ok. Thank you!